# Fetching rows from two tables using single query

Tags: sql, performance

I have two tables say Table A and Table B. The table A and B do not have direct relationship with each other. Need to fetch list of rows combining data of both the tables after applying sort based on combination of certain columns from both the tables.

Eg

```
Table A
id.    name.   age
 1.    test.   11

Table B
id.      user name.    age
1        test1         12
```

Expected result

```
A.id.    B.id.    name   user name

1        null     test.   null
null     1        null    test1
```

Here sort is done based on column age from both the tables.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If these tables are not related, why not use two queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` and `order by` together.  But the ordering has to be based on columns being selected.  Alas.  So the solution is a subquery to combine all the columns with `age`.  Then select only the ones you want:

```
select a_id, b_id, name, user_name
from ((select a.id as a_id, null as b_id, a.name, null as user_name, a.age
       from a
      ) union all
      (select null, b.id, null, b.user_name, b.age
       from b
      )
     ) a
order by age;
```